# Intent Activity Utils , not declarated in Manifest - Kotlin, Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, kotlin-android-extensions, kotlin-extension

I am trying to achieve Intent Activity Utils as extended functions in Kotlin. They will start activities from other Activity/Fragment. Please suggest to me the best way to do that().

I tried to solve that problem like that:

In Activity I invoke extend functions like that :

```
     when (view.id) {
        PROFILE.actionViewId -> {
            // Start Activity normally
            startNewActivity(MyProfileActivity::class.java) 
        }
        PREPAID_RECHARGE.actionViewId -> {
            // Dont start activity  and crash
            startNewActivityForResult(RechargePrepaidActivity::class.java, RECHARGE_PREPAID_REQUEST_CODE) 
            // Start Activity normally 
            this.startActivityForResult(Intent(this, RechargePrepaidActivity::class.java), RECHARGE_PREPAID_REQUEST_CODE) 
        }
        TROUBLE_TICKETS.actionViewId -> {
            startNewActivity(TroubleTicketsActivity::class.java) // Start Activity normally
        }
        HELP.actionViewId -> {
            startNewActivity(HelpSectionActivity::class.java) // Start Activity normally
        }
```

IntentUtils.kt:

```
fun <T : BaseActivity> BaseActivity.startNewActivity(newActivity: Class<T>) {
    val intent = Intent(this, newActivity)
    this.startActivity(intent)
}

//fun BaseActivity.startNewActivity(newActivity: Class<*>) {
//    val intent = Intent(this, newActivity)
//    this.startActivity(intent)
//}

fun BaseActivity.startNewActivityForResult(newActivity: Class<*>, requestCode : Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this, newActivity::class.java)
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
}

fun BaseFragment.startNewActivity(newActivity: Class<*>) {
    val intent = Intent(this.requireActivity(), newActivity::class.java)
    this.startActivity(intent)
}

fun BaseFragment.startNewActivityForResult(newActivity: Class<*>, requestCode : Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this.requireActivity(), newActivity::class.java)
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
}
```

and also, the Activity is declared in the Manifest - Kotlin, Android

```
        <activity
        android:name=".ui.recharge.RechargePrepaidActivity"
        android:configChanges="locale|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
```

This starts activity normally:

```
    startNewActivity(MyProfileActivity::class.java) // use extend func
    startActivity(Intent(this, MyProfileActivity::class.java)) // use inherited Activity func
```

But when I try to create the same function for starting activity for result via request code it doesn't work, when I use inherited Activity function `startActivityForResult()` it's ok

```
            // Dont start activity and crash
            startNewActivityForResult(RechargePrepaidActivity::class.java, RECHARGE_PREPAID_REQUEST_CODE) 
            // Start Activity normally 
            startActivistyForResult(Intent(this, RechargePrepaidActivity::class.java), RECHARGE_PREPAID_REQUEST_CODE)
```

The strange here is that when I use my `IntentUtils.startNewActivityForResult()` app crashes with
`ActivityNotFoundException`, but on normal use of `Fragment.startActivityForResult()`   it doesn't have this behaviour:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
     Unable to find explicit activity class {/java.lang.Class}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
    at ui.utils.view.IntentUtilsKt.startNewActivityForResult(IntentUtils.kt:19)
    at ui.main.hamburgerMenu.HamburgerMenuActivity.onClick(HamburgerMenuActivity.kt:117)
```

Comment: I'm not sure from how you phrased your question. Is RechargePrepaidActivity registered in your manifest or not? You can only start Activities that are registered in the manifest.

Comment: yes it's registered in the manifest, that's the confusing part, I start the intent without any problem by the usual way: `startActivistyForResult(Intent(this, RechargePrepaidActivity::class.java), RECHARGE_PREPAID_REQUEST_CODE)`

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the duplicated `::class.java` invocation :

WRONG:

```
fun BaseActivity.startNewActivityForResult(newActivity: Class<*>, requestCode : Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this, newActivity::class.java) //duplicated ::class.java
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode) 
 }
```

RIGHT:

```
fun BaseActivity.startNewActivityForResult(newActivity: Class<*>, requestCode : Int) {
    val intent = Intent(this, newActivity) // removed ::class.java
    startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode)
 }
```